# Magento 2 product image not displaying on frontend and backend

Tags: image, magento-2.0

I just want to ask why the thumbnail product images in the backend is not displaying. As well as the product image at the product details page on frontend. I'm using Magento 2.0 and my hosting provider is Godaddy....

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue on Magento-2.2.1.Below solution has worked in my case.

Go to `SYSTEM > cache management` and refresh all cache types.

Still if images are not loading, Execute this step in magento root folder: `sudo php bin/magento indexer:reindex`